# Write an argument to a string in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write an argument to a string. What am I doing wrong?
How would it be more correct to write the argument from getopt to a string?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char fsrt[100], sstr[100], tstr[100];
    int rez = 0;
    while ( (rez = getopt(argc, argv, "f:s:l:")) != -1 )
    {
        if (rez == 'f') {
                strcat(fsrt, optarg);
        }
        if (rez == 's') {
                strcat(sstr, optarg);
        }
        if (rez == 'l') {
                strcat(tstr, optarg);
        }
    }


    printf("%s %s %s", fsrt, sstr, tstr);

    return 0;
}
```

Update:
strange symbol in output.

```
./test -f one -s two -l three
output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kksVh.png
```

Comment: Initialize, Initialize, Initialize.

Comment: State the input you're providing to your program via the command line, the output you expected to get, and the output you are actually receiving, in your post above. Include  any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: You cannot use a function meant for string concatenation on things that are not (yet) strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char fsrt[100] = "", sstr[100]= "", tstr[100]= "";
```

If you don't initialize the char arrays they randomly point somewhere in memory.

Comment: Or by doing `char fsrt[100] = { '\0' },....` or `memset(fsrt, '\0', sizeof(fsrt));`.

Comment: or by using `strcpy()` instead of `strcat)`- The example doesn't show any reason why `strcat()` is used. The answer could be improved if it made clear that `strcat()` is intended to add something to an existing string rather than "write an argument to a string" as in the title of the question

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt `strncpy()`

Comment: The formulation "randomly point" is incorrect. An array does not "point" anywhere. An array is not a pointer, even if it [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer in many situations. Even when an uninitialized array with indeterminate (i.e. random) values decays to a pointer, the value of this pointer will not have an indeterminate value, so it will not "randomly point" anywhere. Instead, the decayed pointer will point to the first element of the uninitialized array.